# Selecting average value from multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 columns in mysql database i.e. totalRating and ratingDate. There exists multiple values of totalRating against on date e.g. there can be 5 totalRatings on date 2016-08-29, 4 on 2016-08-30. I am using ChartJs to show a graph of totalRating and ratingDate. I want to take the average of totalRatings of a single date and plot it on graph i.e. one totalRating for one date. I am using PHP for the backend. Can somebody help me with the queries?

Comment: What have you tried (provide the code) and why it failed (describe the problem)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using below query you can find average rating for all dates.

```
select AVG(totalRatings) as avgRating, date from YOUR_TABLE group by date;
```

Comment: Thank you Rahul. That is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is the AVG mysql function, your query should be something like:

```
select AVG(totalRatings) from YOUR_TABLE where date=YOUR_DATE;
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer Thomas. This is what I am doing already

$query = sprintf("SELECT RatingDate, AVG(TotalRating) FROM ratingData WHERE RatingDate = '2016-08-29' ");

I want to select averages for all the dates in database. How do I do that?